# Why the datatable header missing after click filter button in Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatable

I want to filter the data and managed to do it. However, when I clicked filter, my datatable headers are missing but I couldnt figure out what the problem is. 
My blade is:

```
 <table id="table_data" class=" table-responsive table-striped table-hover table-bordered ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                </table>
```

Filter function:

```
$('#filter').click(function(){
      var table = $('#table_data').DataTable();
      var name= $('#name').val();
      var age= $('#age').val();
      var gender= $('#gender').val();

      if( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#table_data')){
            table.destroy();
            $('#table_data').empty();
            var dataTable = $('#table_data').DataTable({
            processing: false,
            serverSide: false,
            ajax:{
            url:'/filter-result',
            data:{name:name, age:age,gender:gender}
            },

            columns: [
                  {
                      data:'id',
                      name:'id'
                  },
                  {
                      data:'First_name',
                      name:'First_name'
                  },
                  {
                      data:'Last_name',
                      name:'Last_name'
                  }

              ]

          });


          }
    });
```

What is the reasons the header missing after clicked?